# Designing React Hooks prevent react-hooks/exhaustive-deps warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, react-hooks

I am designing a hook to fetch data only when the hooks dependencies change. **It works as expected** but I receive the linter warnings:

```
React Hook useEffect was passed a dependency list that is not an array literal. This means we can't statically verify whether you've passed the correct dependencies.
```

and

```
React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'data', 'errorHandler', 'route', and 'successHandler'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. If 'successHandler' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback.
```

As far as I am aware I do not want all these vars in my dependencies as I don't want to fire this hook when these change, I only want to fire it when the dependencies I pass change.

**Question:**
How can I design `useFetch()` hook in a way that coincides with the hooks linter standards (if my design pattern is not up to par, please elaborate on how best this should be accomplished).

My `useFetch()` hook

```
function useFetch(
    {
        route,
        data = {},
        successHandler,
        errorHandler,
    },
    dependencies = []) {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        postJson({route}, data)
            .then(
                res => {
                    if(isFunction(successHandler)) successHandler(res);
                },
                ({responseJSON: err}) => {
                    if(isFunction(errorHandler)) {
                        errorHandler(err);
                    } else {
                        notify({text: err.message || messages.saveFailed(), cssClass: 'error'});
                    }
                }
            )
            .finally(() => {
                setLoading(false);
            });
    }, dependencies);
    return loading;
}
```

Component using `useFetch()`

```
function MyComponent({data, selectedReviewId, setField}) {
    const loading = useFetch({
        route: 'foo.fetchData',
        data: {crrType, clientId, programId, userId},
        successHandler: d => setField([], d) // setField() will set data with the value fetched in useFetch() 
    }, [selectedReviewId]);

    return loading ? <SpinnerComponent/> : <div>{data.foo}</div>;
}
```

Comment: My suggestion's are, anyways you have staticlly assigning empty array to dependencies variable and then provided that variable as dependency array, you should directly provide empty array. Another is don't destructure your props, instead you can use `props.data`, `props.route` in useEffect directy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have passed dependency as array but on the receiving end, it's essentially a single variable pointing to an array. Lint rule of `useEffect()` requires that you pass dependencies in square brackets like done in following code.

Now some technical stuff. Remember what's generating the warning. It's the lint which checks code syntactically. It doesn't go into semantics. Semantically, your list of dependencies is correct, as you are passing an array but syntactically, it's not being passed as an array i.e. it's a single variable not passed in square brackets (like this `[dependencies]`) (which is something lint is looking for). So in order to satisfy lint, you should write:

```
useEffect(
  () => { // implementation of function },
  [dependencies]
);
```

Further, as you are sending an array of dependencies, you can also use spread operator, like this:

```
useEffect(
  () => { // implementation of function },
  [...dependencies]
);
```

This will spread the array elements inside array operator by Babel transpiler. Lint will also remain quiet.

Comment: Spreading the dependencies will result in the same result afaict :/, thank you for the answer though

Comment: It may be different. It depends on how deep react is looking into dependencies. If it's just looking at bindings of variables passed as dependencies, array spread seems better option. If react is performing deep comparison, then simply writing dependencies inside square brackets will be sufficient.

Comment: The lint rule doesn't like spread dependencies, so you'll still need to disable the lint rule either for the file or for the line.

Answer (score 1):

The `eslint` warning is right - you should include those as dependencies. For example, in your `MyComponent` if `data` changes, and it is not in your dependency list, your `useEffect` hook will be calling fetch will outdated `data`.

Same applies to others - it's advised to add those to your dependencies list.

For the first error, it is **probably** ok - even though not ideal. You have a dynamic dependencies list - `eslint` can't be sure if you have all the required stuff in there.

Your solution is probably going to work - but it is very fragile. If your `dependencies` happen to change (e.g. additional elements, or removed elements)

Comment: How would you go about resolving it?