# React useEffect forces me to add dependencies that trigger an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

Why is React forcing me with their linter plugin to add dependencies that I don't want?

For example, I want my effect to trigger only when a certan value changes, yet the linter tells me to add even functions to the dependencies, and I don't want that.

Why it forces me to do that? What do I gain from that?

```
  /**
   * Gets all items, pages, until 250th.
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    if (loadUntil250th && !paginationProps.complete) {
      mounted && setLoading(true);
      let limit = 250 - paginationProps.page * BATCH_LIMIT;
      fetchListItems(paginationProps, limit, paginationProps.page * BATCH_LIMIT)
        .then((results) => {
          if (mounted) {
            setPaginationProps({
              ...paginationProps,
              page: 250 / BATCH_LIMIT,
              autoLoad: false,
              complete: paginationProps.totalItems <= 250,
            });
            setListItems(results.listItems);
            setLoading(false);
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          logger.log('LOADMORE FAILED:', err);
          mounted && setPaginationProps({ ...paginationProps, complete: true });
          mounted && setLoading(false);
        });
    }
    return () => {
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, [loadUntil250th]);
```

It wants this array of dependencies, which result in a infinite loop

```
[loadUntil250th, logger, paginationProps, setListItems]);
```

I want to understand why it is required, if I don't want them.

Comment: Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58866796/understanding-the-react-hooks-exhaustive-deps-lint-rule

Answer (score 2):

The 'exhaustive-deps' lint rule is designed to protect against [*stale closures*](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function), where `useEffect` references props or state used in the callback but not present in the dependency array. Since `logger`, `paginationProps`, and `setListItems` can theoretically change between renders, it's not safe to reference them inside `useEffect` without also including them in the dependency array to ensure you're always receiving and acting on up-to-date data. You can think of useEffect as essentially generating a snapshot of all state and props when it gets created and *only* updating that if one of its dependencies changes.

For instance, without including `paginationProps` in the dependencies list, if `fetchListItems` ever modifies the value of `paginationProps` then `useEffect` won't have access to that updated value until `loadUntil250th` changes.

As referenced in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58866796/understanding-the-react-hooks-exhaustive-deps-lint-rule), part of the issue is that your usage of useEffect() is *unidiomatic*. If all you're doing is subscribing to changes to `loadUntil250th`, you'd be better off moving this function elsewhere and calling it with your code that modifies `loadUntil250th`.

If you want to keep your code in the `useEffect` hook, you have a few options:

1. Assuming that `paginationProps` and `setPaginationProps` are derived from a `useState` hook, you can eliminate the dependency on `paginationProps` by [passing a *function*](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to `setPaginationProps` instead of an object. So your code would become:

```
setPaginationProps(paginationProps => {
    ...paginationProps,
    page: 250 / BATCH_LIMIT,
    autoLoad: false,
    complete: paginationProps.totalItems <= 250,
});
```

2. Move `setListItems` [*inside* the `useEffect` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies) if possible. This ensures that you can control whatever props/state that function depends on. If that's not possible, you have a few options. You can move the function *outside the component* altogether to guarantee that it doesn't depend on props or state. Alternatively, you can use the [`useCallback` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) along with the function to control its dependencies and then list `setListItems` as another dependency.
3. It's unlikely that the `logger` function changes between renders, so you're probably safe keeping that inside your dependency array (although it's odd that the linter would expect that).

If you're still curious, [this article](https://reacttraining.com/blog/useEffect-is-not-the-new-componentDidMount/) is helpful at detailing how `useEffect` and the dependency array actually works.