# Third party API needs to access state in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We have a React app which communicates with a third party library for phone integration. Whenever someone calls, the third-party library triggers a callback function inside the React app. That has been fine until now, but now this callback function needs to access the current state which seems to pose a problem. The state inside of this callback function, seems to always be at the initial value and never updates.

I have made a small sandbox here to describe the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-panini-0kge6?file=/src/App.js

In the sandbox, the counter value is updated correctly when I click "Internal increase". However, the same function has been added as a callback to ThirdPartyApi, which is called when I click "External increase". When I do that, the counter value reverts to whatever is the default in useState.

How can I make the third library be aware of state updates from inside React?

App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ThirdPartyApi from "./third-party-api";
import "./styles.css";

let api = new ThirdPartyApi();

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(5);

  const increaseCounter = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
    console.log(counter);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    api.registerCallback(increaseCounter);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>
        <button onClick={() => increaseCounter()}>Internal increase</button>
      </p>

      <p>
        <button onClick={() => api.triggerCallback()}>External increase</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

third-party-api.js:

```
export default class ThirdPartyApi {
  registerCallback(callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
  }

  triggerCallback() {
    this.callback();
  }
}
```

Comment: Kindly add the minimum viable code directly into the question, thanks.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Notice that unlike the sandbox, we have no control over the third party code in the "real" scenario...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap `increaseCounter()` into a callback via [React's useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback).
As it is, `api.registerCallback()` rerenders because of it, resetting `counter`.

You can learn more about this behavior [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58866796/understanding-the-react-hooks-exhaustive-deps-lint-rule).

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class ThirdPartyApi {
  registerCallback(callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
  }

  triggerCallback() {
    this.callback();
  }
}

let api = new ThirdPartyApi();

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(5);

  const increaseCounter = useCallback(() => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
    console.log(counter);
  }, [counter]);

  useEffect(() => {
    api.registerCallback(increaseCounter);
  }, [increaseCounter]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>
        <button onClick={() => increaseCounter()}>Internal increase</button>
      </p>

      <p>
        <button onClick={() => api.triggerCallback()}>External increase</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

Comment: Keep in mind this will register the callback on every update.