# How to fix "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency. Either include it or remove the dependency array" problem?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-hooks, react-typescript

I want to use `useEffect`, but when I add `getUpperGroup` method, I get warning:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getUpperGroups'. Either include it or remove the dependency array"

My code is:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getUpperGroups();
  setContentData(contentGroupData);
}, [contentGroupData]);


const [contentData, setContentData] = useState<Fundation[]>([] as Fundation[]);
const [upperGroups, setUpperGroups] = useState({});

const getUpperGroups = () => {

   let newUpperGroups = upperGroups;

   contentGroupData.forEach(content=>{
     newUpperGroups = {...newUpperGroups, [content.id]: content.title};
   })

   setUpperGroups(newUpperGroups);
}
```

Comment: You can move the definition of `getUpperGroups` into `useEffect`.

Comment: How? Can you explain more?

Comment: i ignored the warning, its working :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two mistakes.

1- You defined getUpperGroups after useEffect, so you can't add it to the list of useEffect dependencies.

2- if you add getUpperGroups to list of useEffect dependencies, useEffect will run on every re-render and you give a loop of re-render error.

So there is two solutions.

1- Add getUpperGroups into useEffect

```js
const [contentData, setContentData] = useState<Fundation[]>([] as Fundation[]);
const [upperGroups, setUpperGroups] = useState({});


useEffect(() => {
  
  const getUpperGroups = () => {

   let newUpperGroups = upperGroups;

   contentGroupData.forEach(content=>{
     newUpperGroups = {...newUpperGroups, [content.id]: content.title};
   })

   setUpperGroups(newUpperGroups);
  }

  getUpperGroups();
}, [contentGroupData]);
```

2- Disable eslint

```js
useEffect(() => {
  getUpperGroups();
  setContentData(contentGroupData);

  // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [contentGroupData]);


const [contentData, setContentData] = useState<Fundation[]>([] as Fundation[]);
const [upperGroups, setUpperGroups] = useState({});

const getUpperGroups = () => {

   let newUpperGroups = upperGroups;

   contentGroupData.forEach(content=>{
     newUpperGroups = {...newUpperGroups, [content.id]: content.title};
   })

   setUpperGroups(newUpperGroups);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This one worked for me.

Just add this comment at the last line of useEffect:

//eslint-disable-next-line

```
useEffect(() => {
  getUpperGroups();
  setContentData(contentGroupData);
  //eslint-disable-next-line
}, [contentGroupData]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either:

1. Suppress that rule for the entire project: Go to .eslintrc file and change `'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'error'` to `'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'warn'` or `'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'off'`
2. Supress the rule only in this instance:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getUpperGroups();
    setContentData(contentGroupData);
}, [contentGroupData]);


const [contentData, setContentData] = useState<Fundation[]>([] as Fundation[]);
const [upperGroups, setUpperGroups] = useState({});

const getUpperGroups = () => {

    let newUpperGroups = upperGroups;

    contentGroupData.forEach(content=>{
        newUpperGroups = {...newUpperGroups, [content.id]: content.title};
    })

    setUpperGroups(newUpperGroups);
} // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Comment: I don't understand. You fix the error by turning off the message? This is what it sounds like for me, unless you can explain that what's happening is not actually a valid warning? Can you please clarify.

Comment: That is an eslint warning, so it is trying to tell you that this is not "good practice" or this is not recommended as there might be some unexpected/undesired behavior as a result. You can read more here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58866796/understanding-the-react-hooks-exhaustive-deps-lint-rule]. I hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

Probably I would try to move the definition of `getUpperGroups` into `useEffect`. Also you can use `.map()` and the previous state of your `groups` state.

Try as the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getUpperGroups = () => {
     setUpperGroups(prevUpperGroups => contentGroupData.map((content) => ({
        ...prevUpperGroups,
        [content.id]: content.title
     })))
  }

  getUpperGroups();
  setContentData(contentGroupData);
}, [contentGroupData]);
```

Comment: Now, i got error: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'upperGroups'. :(

Comment: @SametSunman Also I've modified now to use `.map()` instead and the previous state of your `upperGroups` which eliminates this issue.