# useEffect calls itself too many times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-query

There is a tree-like structure which should be expanded to make all checked children visible.

Here is the code:

```
  const { data } = useGetData(); // react-query hook that gets data from an endpoint
```

Next, there is a function that returns an array with a node's parents nodes:

```
  const getAllParents = (key: string, parentNodes: string[]) => {
    Object.keys(data).forEach((itemKey: string) => {
      if (
        data[itemKey]?.hasChildren &&
        data[itemKey].children?.filter((child: string) => child === key).length
      ) {
        parentNodes.push(itemKey);
        getAllParents(itemKey, parentNodes);
      }
    });

    return parentNodes;
  };
```

And here is the useEffect, that should run once after the tree is loaded:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let allParents: string[] = [];
    let uniqueParents: string[] = [];
    selectedItems.forEach((item) => {
      const itemParents: string[] = getAllParents(item, []);
      allParents = [...allParents, ...itemParents];
      uniqueParents = [...new Set(allParents)];
    });
    setExpandedItems(uniqueParents);
  }, [getAllParents, selectedItems, uniqueParents]);
```

The problem is that this useEffect run continuously. There is a way to stop it from doing that, by removing `getAllParents` from dependency array.

But doing this shows the warning: *React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getAllParents'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.*

Anyway, it still doesn't work fine, it should only run once when the tree is loaded. Any ideas how to do that?

**UPDATE AFTER ADDING USECALLBACK:**

I have wrapped `getAllParents` inside a useCallback:

```
const getAllParents = useCallback((key: string, parentNodes: string[]) => { ... }, [data]);
```

For useEffect:

- if the dependency array is empty (`[]`): it doesn't run at all, the tree is not expanded
- `[getAllParents, selectedItems]`: it will run forever again
- `[ selectedItems]`: it seems to work fine but with the same warning about a missing dependency.

Comment: This will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64499336/how-to-fix-react-hook-useeffect-has-a-missing-dependency-either-include-it-or

Answer (score 2):

If the `getAllParents` is defined inside the React component, `useEffect` will treat it as a new function with each render (comparing by reference).
Try wrapping it with `useCallback` to avoid creating a new function for every render

Comment: doesn't work, I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

you can try to wrap the `getAllParents` function with `React.useCallback` hook

Comment: doesn't work, I updated the question

Comment: You can also pass a dependency array to `useCallback`.

Comment: @Abhishekkamal what should that array contain? it has `data` for now

Comment: You can write a comment `//eslint-disable-next-line` to the last line inside `useEffect` to get rid of warning about `missing dependency`.