# React hooks: functoin, callback memo

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I was reading how to use react hooks, `callback`, and `memo` adequately. It was mentioned on one of the post that a bad implementation will cost more vs not using `useMemo`

We started implementing  our code to exactly separate the code for UI logic and for the view only

for example, we created a custom hook that handles the UI logic

**controller**

```
const useController  = () {
    const [click, setClick] = useState(0)
    const refresh = () => {
       setClick(0)
    }
    const onClick = () => {
      setClick(click + 1)
   }
   return {
       click, onClick, resfresh
   }
}
```

**component**

```
const Component = () => {
   const {click, onClick, resfresh} = useController()
   return(
     <div>
        <label onClick={onClick}>{click}</label>
        <button onClick={refresh}>refresh</button>
     </div>
   )
}
```

My question here is whether the functions inside the hook are as well recreated when the component is re-rendered. If so, should it be ok to wrap a function inside a custom hook with `useCallback` or `useMemo` if there's an actual need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're creating new handler functions every time Component rerenders - but if the only children of the component are built-in JSX elements, it'll have no noticeable effect at all.

If you wanted to return a stable reference to the functions - which would be a good practice but not necessary - yes, it'd be perfectly fine (and expected) to use `useCallback` or `useMemo`.

```
const useController  = () {
    const [click, setClick] = useState(0);
    const refresh = useCallback(() => {
       setClick(0);
    }, []);
    const onClick = useCallback(() => {
      setClick(click => click + 1);
   }, []);
   return {
       click, onClick, refresh // make sure to spell this right
   };
};
```

Whether `useMemo` or `useCallback` are used would matter more if you had other React components who were children of the Component component use them.

```
const Component = () => {
   const {click, onClick, resfresh} = useController();
   return(
     <SomeOtherComponent {...{ click, onClick, refresh }} /> // make sure to spell this right
   );
};
```

Making sure the references are as stable as possible can make thing easier performance-wise (...in unusual situations) and can also make their uses easier, especially in conjunction with the common [exhaustive-deps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58866796/understanding-the-react-hooks-exhaustive-deps-lint-rule) linting rule.