# concatenation state in useEffect cause loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, infinite-loop

i had read some questions and article about this issue including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58866796/understanding-the-react-hooks-exhaustive-deps-lint-rule) one:
but i don't find my answer.

consider this code.

```
function Component({ page }) {
  
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    
    axios.get([url] + page).then(newList => {
      setList([...list, ...newList]);
    });
    
  }, [page, list]);
  
  return ['some jsx for map though list'];
};
```

i have a pagination and every time i go to next page i need to concatenate the data with previous one, here is the deal.

- the react complains about dependency array about `list` and `page`.
- i'm agree about `page` because each time it changes i need to fetch more data. but when i add `list` to dependency array `useEffect` find changes in `list` and fetch more data which cause infinit loop.

i know about hooks but i wonder what is the best practise to solve this issue.

Comment: best is to remove `list` from dependency array.

Comment: @MohitSharma he needs page in the dependency array so he gets the new list when the page changes

Comment: i change in my first comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list updates on each `page` or `list` dependency update, resulting in an infinite loop. Removing the `list` argument from the dependency array will fix your bug.

In fact, if you use `callback` in `setState` like blew eslint never complain about the `list` in the dependency array. so you can safely remove the list from `useEffect` dependency array.

Inside the `useEffect`, you'd not need `list` at all.

```
useEffect(() => {
    
    axios.get([url] + page).then(newList => {
      setList(prev => [...prev, ...newList]);
    });
    
  }, [page]);
```

Since the method is defined in this component, you'd not even need `useCallback` hooks to memoize the funtion. And `eslint` won't throw warnings too

Comment: this is a sample code but react complain about the list and told me you have to add the list in the dependency array.

Comment: Are you using react18? In that case, I might have to look up the latest documentation for `useEffect`. Another workaround might be to use `useMemo` for your list and remove `useState` and `useEffect` completely

Comment: if `eslint` give you prob then paste this `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` end of useEffect hook.   
like this one   
`useEffect(() => {
    if (_createChannelSuccess) {
      closeDialog();
      dispatch(createChannelSuccess(false))
    }
 // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [])`

Comment: the react version is 17.0.2 @kanuos

Comment: @AmirRezvani in that case there shouldn't be any problem, try removing all `list` variable usage inside the `useEffect` and add `setList` to the dependency array

Comment: sorry @kanuos i did not see you used callback inside of setState so i accept your answer.

Comment: @AmirRezvani I'm glad it solved your issue. BTW, it's not because I used a `callback` inside `setList` that `eslint` didn't scream. In your initial question you were using the `list` variable directly inside the `useEffect`. Since you were using it and not adding it in dependency array, esLint was complaining. However, on adding it in dependency array it rendered an infinite loop. I used a callback as that always gets the previous value of the state.

Comment: @kanuos exactly. i was aware of adding list cause infinite loop because of directly use inside of useEffect what is i am not aware of was if we use callback in setState we use the list indirectly and eslint never complaining about it. thanks to you i know now.