# Rule react-hooks/exhaustive-deps and over-optimization with useCallback

Tags: reactjs, eslint, memoization

There are a lot of post about the eslint rule react-hooks/exhaustive-deps, and also about the good usage of the memoizations hooks `useMemo` and `useCallback` which are generally way overused, but I haven't found any good answers to the following question:

How can I mix the policy of not doing over-optimization by using `useMemo` and `useCallback` in the early stage of the development of an application, and still follow the react-hooks/exhaustive-deps rule?

For example if I have a `useEffect` that will execute a function when a value changes:

```
useEffect(() => { myFunction(); }, [value])
```

But here eslint will tells me that I need to pass `myFunction` to the dependency array, which may lead lead to an infinite loop except I put `myFunction` into a `useCallback` with `value` in the dependency array (and `myFunction` in the one of the `useEffect`).

I'm not sure what is the best practice here, I wanted to avoid using memoization for such simple functions because `useCallback` can be actually quite demanding in terms of performance.

I've made some research about one topic and the other, but I didn't find any useful information concerning both.

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58959298/13491714) that explains when not to use `useEffect`, but I think there still are some use case where the use of a function defined in the components is needed inside of a `useEffect` callback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix missing dependency warning when using useEffect React Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook)

Comment: Not really, no answers talk about performance. I know that memoizing the function will make the application follow the eslint rule, but i don't want to be forced to used memoization hooks because it is against the logic of preventing over-optimization at early stage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Edit

Ultimately Eslint is just a dumb style checker. Writing your entire code strictly following eslint rules will only lead to bad underperforming code. Its all about finding what exactly suites your use case:

1. The recommended way is to have the function inside the useEffect block / use memoization. Ultimately why is eslint forcing to have function as depdendency? - Because people make mistakes, forget dependencies. Having the rule set is better than having people forget few ones.
2. If you feel all your dependencies are covered, ignore eslint, no need to add the function to the dependency list.

---

In general it is highly recommended to keep the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` rule on. It is only safe to omit a function from the dependency list if nothing in it (or the functions called by it) references props, state, or values derived from them. In case of functions there are basically two ways to avoid the warning.

1. You can move the function inside useEffect:

```js
function DependencyTest({ value }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const myFunction = () => value;
    myFunction();
  }, [value]);
}
```

2. useCallback to memoize the function and add it to dependencies:

```
function DependencyTest({ value }) {
  const myFunction = useCallback(() => value, [value]);

  useEffect(() => {
    myFunction();
  }, [myFunction]);
}
```

In order to avoid performance issues I would go with the first one. The same thing is referred to in the react docs: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies

Comment: But what if i need this function to be callable from from another location ?

Comment: Move it outside of the component in that case if your function is guaranteed to not be dependent on any props or state.

If not, then useCallback can be the last resort.

Comment: Your answer doesn't apply to my question, the issue here is not how to work with the eslint rule, but what is the best practice concerning the needs to avoid over-optimization. Memoization hooks are not to use for any value / function because it would actually be counter-performing. So why an eslint rule force me to use useCallback ? I really want to know what is the best practice here

Comment: eslint is just a dumb style checker. Writing your entire code strictly following eslint rules will only lead to bad underperforming code. Its all about finding what exactly suites your use case:

1. If you feel all your dependencies are covered, ignore eslint, no need to add the function to the dependency list.
2. The recommended way is to have the function inside the useEffect block / use memoization. 
Ultimately why is eslint forcing to have function as depdendency?
- Because people make mistakes, forget dependencies. Having the rule set is better than having people forget few ones.

Comment: Yeah i think you are right. Can you edit your answer to add this comment ? I think it answered my question.

Comment: Sure will do that